# How to install postgis extension using an existent version on postgresql on OSX 10.9.4

Tags: postgis, postgresql, osx, homebrew

I'm trying to install postgis using my existent version of postgresql.

I tried doing: `brew install postgis`. But I'm getting the following error trying run `create extension postgis;` query

`PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.2-boxen/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

This is happening because brew is installing a fresh version of postgresql. When I inspect on the new postgres path I can find the missing postgis.control file.

So, the question is: **how can I force postgis to use my existent postgresql installation?**

(I'm using [boxen](https://github.com/boxen/boxen), so It's not an option remove my actual postgres installation)

Comment: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres is the best and quickest method

Comment: @Mapperz it didn't work. The installer requires version 9.3 exactly. I'm not be able to do downgrade to that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to compile postgis from source. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ldlsegovia/3e9b5cba6038de528ee2) that solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install PostGIS on OSX an old Postgres version without upgrading or manual compilation using [Pex](https://github.com/petere/pex):

`git clone git://github.com/petere/pex.git
cd pex
sudo make install
pex init
pex install postgis
psql
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`